# POCO Classes for Flickr API response and RestSharp

Tags: c#, poco, restsharp, flickr

After successfully trying out RestSharp with the Google Elevations API, I wanted to try it on the Flickr API.  For the Elevations API, I created a set of POCO classes that I derived from the XML response to an Elevation query.  I want to do the same for the Flickr API. (I understand there is the wonderful FlickrNet, but I wanted to try with RestSharp).

I have a version of the POCO classes that are working, but I miss some of the information.

Here is a response in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
  <photos page="1" pages="2" perpage="100" total="117">
    <photo id="8626881695" owner="62679167@N05" secret="e82b58b22f" server="8519" farm="9" title="IMG_3149.JPG" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" latitude="51.507431" longitude="-0.122815" accuracy="16" context="0" place_id="I.7fkAxTUrq7FstgaA" woeid="20094318" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1" url_sq="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_e82b58b22f_s.jpg" height_sq="75" width_sq="75" url_t="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_e82b58b22f_t.jpg" height_t="100" width_t="100" url_s="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_e82b58b22f_m.jpg" height_s="240" width_s="240" url_q="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_e82b58b22f_q.jpg" height_q="150" width_q="150" url_m="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_e82b58b22f.jpg" height_m="500" width_m="500" url_n="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_e82b58b22f_n.jpg" height_n="320" width_n="320" url_z="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_e82b58b22f_z.jpg" height_z="640" width_z="640" url_c="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_e82b58b22f_c.jpg" height_c="800" width_c="800" url_l="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_e82b58b22f_b.jpg" height_l="1024" width_l="1024" url_o="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8519/8626881695_a923d82fe6_o.jpg" height_o="2112" width_o="2112" />
    <photo id="8626886683" owner="62679167@N05" secret="f308e6462c" server="8240" farm="9" title="" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" latitude="51.507236" longitude="-0.122338" accuracy="16" context="0" place_id="I.7fkAxTUrq7FstgaA" woeid="20094318" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1" url_sq="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8240/8626886683_f308e6462c_s.jpg" height_sq="75" width_sq="75" url_t="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8240/8626886683_f308e6462c_t.jpg" height_t="100" width_t="100" url_s="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8240/8626886683_f308e6462c_m.jpg" height_s="240" width_s="240" url_q="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8240/8626886683_f308e6462c_q.jpg" height_q="150" width_q="150" url_m="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8240/8626886683_f308e6462c.jpg" height_m="500" width_m="500" url_n="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8240/8626886683_f308e6462c_n.jpg" height_n="320" width_n="320" url_z="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8240/8626886683_f308e6462c_z.jpg" height_z="612" width_z="612" url_o="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8240/8626886683_c98a1a9f02_o.jpg" height_o="612" width_o="612" />
    <photo id="8626885149" owner="62679167@N05" secret="4dde1595e4" server="8387" farm="9" title="IMG_3147.JPG" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" latitude="51.509048" longitude="-0.124458" accuracy="16" context="0" place_id="aOppNH9QV7zH7w" woeid="15652" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1" url_sq="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_4dde1595e4_s.jpg" height_sq="75" width_sq="75" url_t="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_4dde1595e4_t.jpg" height_t="100" width_t="100" url_s="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_4dde1595e4_m.jpg" height_s="240" width_s="240" url_q="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_4dde1595e4_q.jpg" height_q="150" width_q="150" url_m="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_4dde1595e4.jpg" height_m="500" width_m="500" url_n="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_4dde1595e4_n.jpg" height_n="320" width_n="320" url_z="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_4dde1595e4_z.jpg" height_z="640" width_z="640" url_c="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_4dde1595e4_c.jpg" height_c="800" width_c="800" url_l="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_4dde1595e4_b.jpg" height_l="1024" width_l="1024" url_o="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8387/8626885149_8f928ce11a_o.jpg" height_o="2112" width_o="2112" />
    <photo id="8626825995" owner="24343055@N03" secret="0ba9a79f43" server="8262" farm="9" title="Heroes Salute" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" latitude="51.503119" longitude="-0.149366" accuracy="16" context="0" place_id="yy7TEQtVUbhVOw" woeid="43246" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1" url_sq="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_0ba9a79f43_s.jpg" height_sq="75" width_sq="75" url_t="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_0ba9a79f43_t.jpg" height_t="75" width_t="100" url_s="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_0ba9a79f43_m.jpg" height_s="180" width_s="240" url_q="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_0ba9a79f43_q.jpg" height_q="150" width_q="150" url_m="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_0ba9a79f43.jpg" height_m="375" width_m="500" url_n="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_0ba9a79f43_n.jpg" height_n="240" width_n="320" url_z="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_0ba9a79f43_z.jpg" height_z="480" width_z="640" url_c="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_0ba9a79f43_c.jpg" height_c="600" width_c="800" url_l="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_0ba9a79f43_b.jpg" height_l="768" width_l="1024" url_o="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8626825995_309be230ce_o.jpg" height_o="2313" width_o="3085" />
    <photo id="8626826765" owner="24343055@N03" secret="a14c1a395c" server="8526" farm="9" title="Long Overdue" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" latitude="51.503173" longitude="-0.149318" accuracy="16" context="0" place_id="yy7TEQtVUbhVOw" woeid="43246" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1" url_sq="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_a14c1a395c_s.jpg" height_sq="75" width_sq="75" url_t="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_a14c1a395c_t.jpg" height_t="100" width_t="75" url_s="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_a14c1a395c_m.jpg" height_s="240" width_s="180" url_q="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_a14c1a395c_q.jpg" height_q="150" width_q="150" url_m="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_a14c1a395c.jpg" height_m="500" width_m="375" url_n="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_a14c1a395c_n.jpg" height_n="320" width_n="240" url_z="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_a14c1a395c_z.jpg" height_z="640" width_z="480" url_c="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_a14c1a395c_c.jpg" height_c="800" width_c="600" url_l="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_a14c1a395c_b.jpg" height_l="1024" width_l="768" url_o="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8526/8626826765_7db667a6ed_o.jpg" height_o="3121" width_o="2340" />
    <photo id="8626843195" owner="24343055@N03" secret="bf3c7309a5" server="8104" farm="9" title="Bus Bonus" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" latitude="51.503319" longitude="-0.149323" accuracy="16" context="0" place_id="yy7TEQtVUbhVOw" woeid="43246" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1" url_sq="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_bf3c7309a5_s.jpg" height_sq="75" width_sq="75" url_t="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_bf3c7309a5_t.jpg" height_t="100" width_t="75" url_s="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_bf3c7309a5_m.jpg" height_s="240" width_s="180" url_q="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_bf3c7309a5_q.jpg" height_q="150" width_q="150" url_m="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_bf3c7309a5.jpg" height_m="500" width_m="375" url_n="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_bf3c7309a5_n.jpg" height_n="320" width_n="240" url_z="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_bf3c7309a5_z.jpg" height_z="640" width_z="480" url_c="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_bf3c7309a5_c.jpg" height_c="800" width_c="600" url_l="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_bf3c7309a5_b.jpg" height_l="1024" width_l="768" url_o="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8104/8626843195_601d42bdd2_o.jpg" height_o="3067" width_o="2300" />
    <photo id="8626786831" owner="24664325@N06" secret="c30d6881bf" server="8261" farm="9" title="Breaking the girl" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" latitude="51.508234" longitude="-0.128188" accuracy="16" context="0" place_id="1EPGyGtTUrrDXJmGCA" woeid="20094364" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1" url_sq="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8626786831_c30d6881bf_s.jpg" height_sq="75" width_sq="75" url_t="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8626786831_c30d6881bf_t.jpg" height_t="64" width_t="100" url_s="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8626786831_c30d6881bf_m.jpg" height_s="155" width_s="240" url_q="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8626786831_c30d6881bf_q.jpg" height_q="150" width_q="150" url_m="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8626786831_c30d6881bf.jpg" height_m="322" width_m="500" url_n="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8626786831_c30d6881bf_n.jpg" height_n="206" width_n="320" url_z="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8626786831_c30d6881bf_z.jpg" height_z="412" width_z="640" url_c="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8626786831_c30d6881bf_c.jpg" height_c="515" width_c="800" url_l="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8626786831_c30d6881bf_b.jpg" height_l="644" width_l="1000" />
...cut for brevity
  </photos>
</rsp>
```

Here are the POCO classes that work, but miss information:

```
public class Reply
  {
    public string stat {get;set;}
    public List<Photo> photos {get;set;}
  }

  public class Photo
  {
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string owner {get;set;}
    public string secret {get;set;}
    public string server {get;set;}
    public string farm {get;set;}
    public string title {get;set;}
    public string ispublic {get;set;}
    public string isfriend {get;set;}
    public string isfamily {get;set;}
    public string latitude {get;set;}
    public string longitude {get;set;}
    public string accuracy {get;set;}
    public string context {get;set;}
    public string place_id {get;set;}
    public string woeid {get;set;}
    public string geo_is_family {get;set;}
    public string geo_is_contact {get;set;}
    public string geo_is_public {get;set;}
    public string url_sq {get;set;}
    public string height_sq {get;set;}
    public string width_sq {get;set;}
    public string url_t {get;set;}
    public string height_t {get;set;}
    public string width_t {get;set;}
    public string url_s {get;set;}
    public string height_s {get;set;}
    public string width_s {get;set;}
    public string url_q {get;set;}
    public string height_q {get;set;}
    public string width_q {get;set;}
    public string url_m {get;set;}
    public string height_m {get;set;}
    public string width_m {get;set;}
    public string url_n {get;set;}
    public string height_n {get;set;}
    public string width_n {get;set;}
    public string url_z {get;set;}
    public string height_z {get;set;}
    public string width_z {get;set;}
    public string url_c {get;set;}
    public string height_c {get;set;}
    public string width_c {get;set;}
    public string url_l {get;set;}
    public string height_l {get;set;}
    public string width_l {get;set;}
    public string url_o {get;set;}
    public string height_o {get;set;}
    public string width_o {get;set;}

  }
```

I also want to retrieve the attributes in the photos element:

```
<photos page="1" pages="2" perpage="100" total="117">
```

With the above classes I see no logical way of getting to these attributes as I never define them.  I have tried the following classes (the Photo class is the same as above):

```
 public class Reply
  {
    public string stat {get;set;}
    public Photos photos {get;set;}

  }
  public class Photos
  {
    public string page {get;set;}
    public string pages {get;set;}
    public string perpage {get;set;}
    public string total {get;set;}
    public List<Photo> photoList {get;set;}
  }
```

When I try to access `response.Data.photos.page` I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

Could anyone shed some light on how to design the classes to be able to access the attributes in the photos element as well as be able to retrieve the list of photos?

Comment: I have tried http://json2csharp.com which seems like a great time saver, but I still get the same errors when trying to access the deserialized attributes data in the photos element utilizing the classes it creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RestSharp does not deserialize attributes by default. github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization Seems the distinction is that attributes can be deserialized if it is an element without anything else inline (i.e. photo). Elements with attributes and other elements contained within seem to need a custom deserializer. Instead, I used Xml.Linq to access the photos element attributes:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(response.Content); 
IEnumerable<int> page = 
   from item in xDoc.Descendants("photos") 
   select (int) item.Attribute("page"); etc...
```